# GAE: How to redirect?

Tags: google-app-engine, web, dns

I've got a GoDaddy Domain.

I've got a Google App Engine account.

And I've got my domain linked to Google Apps.

Here's the actual site: [www.htmltetris.com](http://www.htmltetris.com)

What i'm trying to do here is to ensure that as many people as possible can all-of-a-sudden access my website (hosted on GAE) through that domain.

Currently it looks like everything already runs, at least my domain (htmltetris.com) actually goes to the GAE server.

Still, if you head to [htmltetris.com](http://htmltetris.com) you end up with crap. What must I change? Should I add a CNAME entry to redirect to www?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518373